# how to remove duplicated frame from 00:00:00,00 to 00:00:00,25 section not overall with mpdecimate filter?

Tags: ffmpeg

how to remove duplicated frame from 00:00:00,00 to 00:00:00,25 (00frame ~ 25frames)section not overall with mpdecimate filter ??
normally  H264 video  have some duplicated frames on video start section ..

```
    i have tried like this , 

1)  ./ffmpeg -i cated_2-3.UMMJI.MTS -map 0:0 -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 1 -qscale:v 8  -s 1920x1080  -r 29.97  -top 1  -c:a pcm_s16le    -map 0:1 -filter:a:0 "pan=mono|c0=c0" -map 0:1 -filter:a:1 "pan=mono|c0=c1"   -metadata:s encoder="Apple ProRes 422 LT"  -filter_complex "[0]split=2[a][b];[a]trim=end_frame=26,mpdecimate[a];[b]trim=start_frame=25,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b];[a][b]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" -vsync vfr -vf blackdetect=d=0.1:pix_th=.1  cated_2-3.UMMJI_MTS_mpdecimate26_section.mov

and  tried to check black_frame on out prores mov file 
2)./ffmpeg  -i cated_2-3.UMMJI_MTS_mpdecimate26_section.mov  -vf blackdetect=d=0.1:pix_th=.1  test.mov

then , will be shown like below 

macmini-master:1.  two_file_test khan$ ./ffmpeg  -i cated_2-3.UMMJI_MTS_mpdecimate26_section.mov  -vf blackdetect=d=0.1:pix_th=.1  test.mov
ffmpeg version N-92108-ge08a876e67-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.2)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      56. 19.101 / 56. 19.101
  libavcodec     58. 32.100 / 58. 32.100
  libavformat    58. 18.104 / 58. 18.104
  libavdevice    58.  4.105 / 58.  4.105
  libavfilter     7. 33.100 /  7. 33.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.2 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cated_2-3.UMMJI_MTS_mpdecimate26_section.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf58.18.104
  Duration: 00:25:12.58, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 86198 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apcs / 0x73637061), yuv422p10le(tv, top first), 1920x1080, 84662 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 11988 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 LT
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (prores (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7f8eb2804200] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7f8eb2804200] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7f8eb2804200] profile High 4:2:2, level 4.0, 4:2:2, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7f8eb2804200] 264 - core 157 r2935 545de2f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mov, to 'test.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf58.18.104
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 11988 tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.32.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.32.100 aac
frame= 8224 fps= 21 q=29.0 size=   86528kB time=00:04:34.49 bitrate=2582.3kbits/s dup=19 drop=0 speed=0.689x
```

as you can see  duplicated frame just changed to black frame , not removed 
this MTS file have 19 duplicated frames  ! 
also i have checked in  FCPX and count how many dupicated frame  on out prores mov file ...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in -filter_complex "[0]split=2[a][b];[a]trim=end_frame=26,mpdecimate[a];[b]trim=start_frame=26,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b];[a][b]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" -vsync vfr out
```